# Unable to execute mysql_upgrade on AWS RDS instance of MariaDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

I have a MariaDb 10.1.34 instance on AWS RDS. This instance has among other things root user with appropriate permissions.

I upgraded the instance to use 10.2.21 version of the MariaDB and wanted to execute [mysql_upgrade](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_upgrade/) as suggested in [offical upgrade document](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading-from-mariadb-101-to-mariadb-102/).

However I always get this error:

```
Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'<instanceip>' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

Using the exact same credentials I can connect to the database using mysql cli but no mysql_upgrade or mysqlcheck.

So this works:

```
mysql --user=root --password=<pwd> --host=<hosturl> --port=3306 --protocol=tcp
```

And this does not:

```
mysql_upgrade --user=root --password=<pwd> --host=<hosturl> --port=3306 --protocol=tcp
```

`SHOW GRANTS FOR root;` gives this output:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX,
      ALTER, SHOW  DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE,
      REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER,
      EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '<sometext>' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save time to to anybody trying to do the same thing - don't.

The behavior I encountered is by AWS design. mysql_upgrade is already executing during the instance upgrade process internally.
([Source for this statement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-upgrading-amazon-rds-for-mysql-and-amazon-rds-for-mariadb/))